# How to read a stack trace in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I inherited an undocumented VB.NET application in order to provide support for some users. I am very new to .NET. The application has a welcome form, that is accessed after logging in, with menus that open other forms.

One of these form (supposed to print some labels) throws a `ObjectDisposedException` error and crashes.

I copied the stack trace (or at least what I think it is) and need to understand what is caused the crash.

For now my research led me to understand `FrmMenu` is causing the error since it is not disposed properly, but I am stuck there.

What should I understand by this trace?

```
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FrmMenu'.
  Source=mscorlib
  ObjectName=FrmMenu
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
       at PrjInv.FrmMenu.applicationIdle_TickAsync(Object sender, TickEventArgs e) in C:\TFSSolution\FrmMenu.vb:line 1805
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
       at System.EventHandler`1.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
       at Winforms.Components.ApplicationIdle.OnTickAsyncCompleted(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in C:\Users\User.User-PC\Desktop\Application Idle Solution\Winforms.Components\ApplicationIdle.cs:line 822
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object o)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
```

Reading from comments, I get these 2 functions.
At line 1805:

```
Private Sub applicationIdle_TickAsync(sender As Object, e As TickEventArgs)
        If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
            Me.CreateHandle()
        End If
        BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() applicationIdle_Tick(sender, e)))
    End Sub
```

And oddly enough

```
Private Sub applicationIdle_Tick(sender As Object, e As TickEventArgs)
        If e.IsWarnPeriod Then
            ' UpdateTimeDisplays(warnColour)
        Else
            ' UpdateTimeDisplays(normalColour)

        End If
    End Sub
```

Yes, the code is commented!!! What should I understand?

Comment: Have a look around the line numbers mentioned in the stack trace. Then possibly start adding errorhandlers top downwards and see what gets caught.

Comment: No idea how, any tutorials?

Comment: Start with `at PrjInv.FrmMenu.applicationIdle_TickAsync(Object sender, TickEventArgs e) in C:\TFSSolution\FrmMenu.vb:line 1805` and especially look at any `CreateHandle` there - what is it creating a handle on? That seems to be disposed. Now it is up to you to figure out *why* (or maybe post that code with explanation, so we can look)

Comment: It is a race condition, the remoting keeps going even though the user closed the form. A basic fix is to add `If (Me.IsDisposed) Return`

Comment: @HansPassant Where should I add it please?

Comment: Before Me.CreateHandle().  Notable is that it is in itself a hack, the code smell is fairly overpowering.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, it does not work.

Comment: You may consider using `Debug.WriteLine` statements placed before and after various statements.